# My gpu is running slower than it should

Tags: nvidia, games, gpu, nvidia-settings, gpu-driver

I have a GTX 750 ti and it's capable of running at 5GT/s, However in the nvidia xserver settings it says it's maximum link speed is 2.5GT/s. How do i change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your PCI-E settings are restricting your GPU's bandwidth. You need to go to your BIOS and select PCI-E 3.0, **if your motherboard supports it**. If not, you're stuck with 2.5 GT/s.

Comment: That explains it, I have an old motherboard. will it affect proformmance by much?

Comment: @DeVanquisher I have the same GPU, and the biggest performance hit will be to the GDDR5 memory included on the GPU- your memory bandwidth will be halved. However, I can attest to the fact that **your performance will not be reduced by much**. You might see a ~10% performance hit *at worst*. If my answer was helpful please mark it as correct :)